# Eclipse Scout Neon ListBox: execValidateValue(..) not working

Tags: validation, listbox, eclipse-scout

I have List box in new Neon Scout and I would like to validate value that was set.

I have implemented `execValidateValue` method :

```
  @Override
  protected Set<String> execValidateValue(final Set<String> rawValue) {

    if (rawValue.contains(CONSTANT.UNKNOWN)) {
      final Set<String> unknownSet = new HashSet<String>();
      unknownSet.add(CONSTANT.UNKNOWN);
      return super.execValidateValue(unknownSet);
    }

    return super.execValidateValue(rawValue);
  }
```

but it doesn't seams to have any effect. While debugging I see that inside `setValue(VALUE rawValue)` method `updateDisplayText(validatedValue)` is called with right list of strings.

Why is that? Is there something that I did wrong?

Marko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right... If a value is changed during the validation (in `execValidateValue(VALUE rawValue)`) as suggested by the JavaDoc, the value is stored correctly in the Scout Model but the change is not reflected in the HTML-UI.

With the help of Samuel Renold, I have asked the team about it: The HTML-UI will be fixed to reflect the change in the UI. See [bug 493778](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=493778).

---

Test code for the Demo Widgets Application. Change the `DefaultField` in the `ListBoxForm`.

```
@Order(20)
public class DefaultField extends AbstractListBox<Color> {

  @Override
  protected Class<? extends ICodeType<?, Color>> getConfiguredCodeType() {
    return ColorsCodeType.class;
  }

  @Override
  protected Set<Color> execValidateValue(Set<Color> rawValue) {
    System.out.println(">> execValidateValue");
    printColors(rawValue);
    if (rawValue != null && rawValue.contains(Color.RED)) {
      return super.execValidateValue(Collections.singleton(Color.RED));
    }
    return super.execValidateValue(rawValue);
  }

  private void printColors(Set<Color> rawValue) {
    if (rawValue != null) {
      for (Color color : rawValue) {
        System.out.print(color + ", ");
      }
      System.out.println("");
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("null");
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void execChangedValue() {
    System.out.println(">> execValidateValue");
    printColors(getValue());

  }

  @Override
  protected int getConfiguredGridH() {
    return 5;
  }

  @Override
  protected String getConfiguredLabel() {
    return TEXTS.get("Default");
  }
}
```

---

The wrong behaviour can also be reproduced in Scout 4 (this release is end-of-life)

Comment: I didn't understand your Test code. Is this for me to help me or for other to see the bug?

Comment: This is test to help other to see the bug.

Comment: This issue will be tracked as Bug 493778: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=493778